# Can we use ping to see packet dropped in traffic control?

Tags: networking, ping

I am studying in traffic control and  want to know how we can check packet dropped in a traffic control that I config it. Can we use ping icmp not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ping to check if there is currently some packet loss, but if you need to see if any packets were dropped before something like "netstat -s" or regularly checking the data in /proc/net/netstat (on unix-like systems) might be more useful.